# Website compilation process[AppCode DLLs]

Tags: c#, app-code

We are working on a website project which contains around 1130 pages. After compilation, all the .aspx.cs files are converted into AppCode DLLs that has random names.

Whenever there are any changes in single .aspx.cs file[like a hotfix], we have to recompile and deploy the entire project on the application host.

We want to update only those files that have been changed and not the entire package.

One of a solution we are aware is that, converting Website to Web application; but we cannot implement that change at this stage of the project.

Is there any other way to find an efficient solution for this?

Comment: So, does my answer helped you in regards to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Talking in Visual Studio 2010:
While publishing the website, Select the option: 'Use Fixed naming and single page assemblies', Also select 'Allow this precompiled site to be updateable'.

After website is published. Go to the published folder. Open any aspx page (not the dll or .cs).. Note the dll name in page attribute under inherits attribute. Than using ftp or any other way to upload, copy or upload tht dll under bin to your website.

Also, you can create a doc or txt file to list all Dll names with respective paths to your file to easily know which dll to upload next time if there is any change.

Hope it helps.